# Need help for C# abstract properties sample code dissection

Tags: c#, abstract-class, overriding

When reading the tutorial of "Properties Tutorial" from MSDN. 
I'm consused about the example.

[How to define abstract properties. ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(VS.71).aspx)

When I debug, I found each of the three override double Area() is invoked by ToString(); and ToString() is invoked default by the WriteLine() calls.

What's the benefit calling this way? 
I feel it is not a short way to override double Area().

```
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return Id + " Area = " + string.Format("{0:F2}",Area);
   }
```

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: This is an example.. I don't understand your question, what's your meaning? Can you give some code for comparing.

Comment: Is it a standard method to override Area() invoded by ToString()? Or is there any other easy style to realize abstract/override relation example. I feel it is not clear to found the relation at the first signt.

Comment: Once you override the property you just use it like any other, the ToString is accessing the property you could accessit any way you like, what is unclear?

Comment: @Paul. ToString is a accessing method as your said. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ToString/writeline methods are not related to overriding Area, it is a demonstration to show the use of an overriden property.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a demo, the author simplely like this way to demo the code I think, but there's no relationships between them.